# Url rewriting mod_rewrite

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I have the url such as:

```
 page.com/content.php?xname=p&yname=q&zid=1
```

I want to rewrite this url using apache mod_rewrite into something like:

```
 page.com/p/q/
```

note there should not be 'zid' parameter in renamed url. I know expressions are passed as GET into the original url.
Is it possible to rename as above. If yes, How to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This one works fine for me and will rewrite request for `/p/q/` to `/content.php?xname=p&yname=q&zid=1`.

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/$ content.php?xname=$1&yname=$2&zid=1 [QSA,L]
```

1. This rule is to be placed in .htaccess in website root folder. If placed elsewhere some small tweaking may be required.
2. It will not rewrite if requested URL is a real file or folder (I'm sure you do not want to rewrite images or some other pages -- I had to add such condition since I do not know what is your website structure is).

Answer (score 1):

```
RewriteRule   ^content\.php\?xname=(p)&yname=(q)&zid=1$    /$1/$2  [R]
```

Instead of p and q you can try expressions like [a-Z0-9_-]+ to match  identifiers.

There's an online testing tool here: http://civilolydnad.se/projects/rewriterule/

Comment: When I write something like this:
RewriteRule ^event/([a-z]+)/([0-9]+)/$ x.php?x=$2

Even though I have entered url  : event/p/6/.
It get renamed to x.php?x=p
What I want is x.php?x=6

Answer (score 0):

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^/[a-z0-9]+/[a-z0-9]+/$ content.php?xname=$1&yname=$2 [L]
```