# htaccess clean urls with folder

Tags: .htaccess

I've always been terrible at getting clean URLs to work.

How do I write the RewriteRule to convert the following clean URL

```
/posts/test-title.php
```

from

```
post-slug.php?slug=test-title
```

Thanks.

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7211259/url-rewriting-mod-rewrite

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
RewriteEngine On
Options +FollowSymlinks
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^posts/(.*) /post-slug.php?slug=$1
```

Not sure if you meant to have the .php extension on your pretty URL.. seems redundant - If you do, then you can just remove the extension in post-slug.php with

```
   $slug_with_ext = str_replace(".php", "", $slug);
```